# Remove Formatting on Chrome Extension Generated Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, formatting

What is a short, quick, and efficient way to remove any formatting from a website's stylesheet on any dynamically generated content from my Chrome Extension?

For example, if I use the code below in my chrome extension to generate a div, the website's stylesheet might format the div so it is longer than I would like, or has more padding than needed, or has rounded corners. How would I prevent this?

```
foo = $("<div/>",{
        "class" : "some class",
        "css" : {
            "background" : "#000",
            "height" : "16px",
            "display" : "none",
            "opacity" : "0.7",
            "position" : "absolute",
            "pointer-events": "none",
            "z-index": "99999"
        }
    }).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with Chrome extensions; you're just a little more likely to encounter it in the context of an extension because you have no idea what kind of page you'll be inserting your elements into. Suppose instead you're building a JavaScript widget of some kind that inserts a button for your new social network into content providers' pages. This is an equivalent problem, but you'll agree the problem is now a pure HTML/CSS problem.

First, pick class names and element IDs that are likely to be distinct. There isn't a perfect solution to this problem, but you can pick names that are really unlikely for anyone else to use, like yourdomain-main, yourdomain-header, etc.

Second, use a "reset-CSS" stylesheet. [Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is one of a million examples on the web. The "might format the div" part that you're worried about is largely taken care of by explicitly setting the expected format in this stylesheet, leaving little room for "might" because you've reset every attribute you care about.

Third, be very explicit in the styles you do count on. For example, rather than expecting your div to expand to fill whatever space it can, set a specific width in a specific number of pixels. You'll probably be the last stylesheet applied for most styles because of the uniqueness step above, but if something is important, don't forget [!important](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Finally, it's helpful to collect a set of hostile environments for your widget, maybe iframe copies of them so you can see them all on one page, and test frequently during development.

Speaking of iframes, a lot of social buttons out there do use iframes to get a more isolated environment. You lose some interactivity with your embedder in these cases; it's a tradeoff.

Comment: so I suppose there's no simple way to clear all the formatting... alright thanks I guess. I'll give you the question answer for your time.

Comment: I've found the easiest way to deal with it is to include my own CSS sheet in the extension and use unique IDs to format the elements. I can format just the ones I add or add/replace the ID on existing elements to reformat them too.